# Symfony 2 Ajax Unexplained error

Tags: jquery, ajax, symfony

I realize that there are a lot of questions on S.O. regarding this topic, and I have perused them. However, I am not finding an answer that satisfies my problem.

I am able to send data via POST to my script just fine. However, I cannot return data back to my calling script. It defaults to my error function immediately. Even more confusing, the error text is blank.

Here is my code:

routing.yml

```
models:
    path: /models
    defaults: {_controller: GPForecastBundle:model:index}

modifydatabase:
    path: /models/modify
    defaults: {_controller: GPForecastBundle:modify:index}
    requirements:
        _method: POST
```

modifyController.php

```
namespace GP\ForecastBundle\Controller;
use PDO;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

class modifyController extends Controller
{
  public function indexAction()
  {

    if ($this->get('request')->isXmlHttpRequest())
{
  try{

  $page = $this->get('request')->request->get('page');
  $offset = $this->get('request')->request->get('offset');
  $start = $page * $offset;

  settype($offset, "int");

  $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx", 'xxx', 'xxx');
  $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM forecastmodels LIMIT :start, :offset;");
  $stmt->bindValue(':start', (int)$start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue(':offset', (int)$offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->execute();
  $contents = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

  mail('myemail@domain', 'Requested Variable', 'catch block did not fire');

  return new JsonResponse(array('success' => true));
  }
  catch (Exception $ex) {
    ob_start();
    var_dump($ex->getMessage());
    $result = ob_get_clean();
    mail('myemail@domain', 'Requested Variable', $result);
    return new JsonResponse(array('success'=>false, 'msg'=>$ex->getMessage()));
  }
}
else {
  echo 'Path is working';
}
  }
}
```

my model.html.twig JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.page').click(function (e) {
        $offset = {{offset}};
        $page = e.target.id;
        $url = document.URL + '/modify';
        $.ajax({
            url: $url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                offset: $offset,
                page: $page
            },
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                console.log("Status: " + textStatus);
            },
            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("Error: " + errorThrown);
            }
        }); //end Ajax call
    }); //end page click event
}); //end document.ready// JavaScript Document
```

The routing is working fine. I know this because I can go to the URL and see the 'This is working' text. In addition, I know that the data I am posting via AJAX is getting there (using mail() to email myself the var_dump of the data I pass). Everything is fine until I get to where I need to return data.

The error function always fires, without fail. In addition, I'm not able to get any kind of information. In my console, the only thing that appears is, and I quote:

```
"Error: "
```

If I try using console.log("Error: " + textStatus) I get

```
"Error: error"
```

Which is enormously helpful.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side note - Why are you instanciating a new PDO instance? What's wrong with doctrine?

Comment: I knew that was going to come up. Suffice to say that I don't want to mess with Doctrine when PDO suits my needs just fine.

Comment: Write some logs using logger, then check the dev log for error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After continuing to bash my head against this problem, I realized that the fact that I was using  tags to proc the jQuery event was causing the trouble.

If anyone runs into this same problem - using a  to activate a jquery Ajax call - using e.preventDefault() directly after your Ajax call will fix it.

Example code:

```
$('.page').click(function (e) {

        $offset = {{offset}};
        $page = e.target.id;
        $.ajax({
            url: $url,
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                offset: $offset,
                page: $page
            },
            success:function(data) {
               console.log('Success');
                },
            error:function(jQXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jQXHR);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(errorThrown);
                }
        }); //end Ajax call
        e.preventDefault();
    }); //end page click event
```

Answer (score 0):

if the error function is always called, that means there is an exception thrown in your server side code.  Use a `try catch` block to catch the exception, and return the exception message.  That way you know what the problem is.

```
public function indexAction()
{
  try{
      $page = $this->get('request')->request->get('page');
      $offset = $this->get('request')->request->get('offset');
      $start = $page * $offset;

      settype($offset, "int");

      $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx", 'yyy', 'zzz');
      $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM forecastmodels LIMIT :start, :offset;");
      $stmt->bindValue(':start', (int)$start, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $stmt->bindValue(':offset', (int)$offset, PDO::PARAM_INT);
      $stmt->execute();
      $contents = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

      return new JsonResponse(array('success' => true));
  catch(\Exception $ex){
      return new JsonResponse(array('success'=>false, 'msg'=>$ex->getMessage()));
  }

}
```

NOTE: This is not advisable for production systems.  Returning an exception message in a production environment is a security risk.  This will work for debugging the issue though.  My guess is that some sort of SQL exception is thrown.

Then your success function should be called no matter what, because you will always be returning a response with status code 200

Comment: This was a good idea. However, no exception is being raised. You can see the code I tried in my original post. The try/catch block is not raising an exception.